# Android Platform Tools: "A stop job is running for Session 2 of UserX", and I have to wait 90 seconds to power down

Tags: linux, systemd, archlinux, systemctl

I have recently begun using KVM acceleration with `libvirtd` on my Arch Linux box for some mobile application development, and now every time I go to shut down the system I have to wait 90 seconds for "A stop job is running for Session 2 of UserX" to complete.

My first thought was that it was the libvirtd daemon refusing to exit gracefully for some reason, but I'm able to stop that process with `systemctl stop libvirtd.service`, although this does not circumvent the 90 second stop job.

What steps can I take to redress this issue?  I don't even know for sure what the stop job actually is, because it isn't specified by the message.

Answer (score 0):

After updating from Android Platform Tools 29.0.1 to 29.0.2 this issue stopped occurring. Go figure.